# jpa findby with list of conditions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am still a beginner with java, here I'm trying to fetch the data from mysql database using JPA.

but I'm getting a problem with setting the list of conditions with find by function.
i can set Object of date even it refused the inputs
below is my code for reference.

**my query :**

```
select t.id, t.MSISDN, t.Param1, t.param2
  from BULK_REPOSITORY t
where t.Camp_Start_Date between Sysdate - 2 and sysdate
   and t.status = 0
   and t.camp_type = 1;
```

Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataJpaApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    Bulk_repository bulk ;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(Bulk_repositoryRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {

            // fetch customers by Status
            log.info("Customer found with findByStatus('0'):");
            log.info("--------------------------------------------");
            repository.findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStart_dateBetween(1,2,Date,Date-2).forEach(on -> {
                log.info(on.toString());
            });
        };
    }
```

Bulk_repositoryRepository class :

```
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

    public interface Bulk_repositoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Bulk_repository, Long> {
          List<Bulk_repository>  findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStart_dateBetween(int status, int campType,Date campStart_dateStart, Date campStart_dateEnd);
         Bulk_repository findById(long id);
    }
```

Bulk_repository:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BULK_REPOSITORY")
public class Bulk_repository {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "msisdn")
   private String msisdn;

   @Column(name = "camp_start_date")   
   private Date campStartDate;

   @Column(name = "camp_end_date")
   private Date campEndDate;

   @Column(name = "camp_type")
   private int campType;

   @Column(name = "camp_cd")
   private String camp_cd;

   @Column(name = "status")
   private int status;

   @Column(name = "process_date")
   private Date processDate;

   @Column(name = "entry_date")
   private Date entryDate;

   @Column(name = "entry_user")
   private String entry_user;

   @Column(name = "param1")
   private String param1;

   @Column(name = "param2")
   private String param2;

   @Column(name = "param3")
   private String param3;

   @Column(name = "param4")
   private String param4;

   @Column(name = "param5")
   private String param5;

   @Column(name = "error_desc")
   private String error_desc;

   @Column(name = "fulfilment_status")
   private int fulfilment_status;
## getter and setter and ToString
```

Comment: just a suggestion, remove underscores (_) from class names and variable name, it is not java standard  plus it will make your life easy in JPA

Comment: i have removed the underscores on needed variables, but still im in trouble with how to define data object, sorry im still kid 12 years old :P

Comment: edit your question and modify your Bulk_repository with latest

Comment: I guess you have accepted an answer as @dasunse suggested, create a fresh question, and put a reference here in comments

Comment: done, I have asked another question

Comment: posted a comment on your new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way,

Escape the `_` by using an additional underscore

```
List<Bulk_repository>  findAllByStatusAndCamp__typeAndCamp__start__dateBetween(int status, int camp_type,Date camp_start_dateStart, Date camp_start_dateEnd);
```

I recommond to use this way in your model class. If so you have to change your repository according to this.

```
@Column(name = "camp_start_date")   
private Date campStartDate; // better to use this way
```

Comment: thank you its worked fine , but now as i understand i have to create date object to be alighned with my query , can show me how ?

Comment: could you please explain more.. Are you asing about this type of scenario. @Query("SELECT b.msisdn from Bulk_repository b where b.status = ?1 ")
List<Bulk_repository> getBylkRepositoryByStatus(int status); Are you asking about how status have passed... is it this type of  scenario..

Comment: im just trying to represent the above query , i have updated my question with query , but im getting problem about how to set date object

Comment: @yongshi it is better to ask a new question. People who view this question again may confusing with question and  answers. because you have asked an edited question and the answers may be for your previous question.

Comment: Instead of giving this much long method name, you can use QueryDSL, Specification, CriteriaQuery

Comment: can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582177/jpa-with-https-request-multithreading-spring/58584987#58584987